# How to add Play Store app testers using the terminal?

Tags: android, google-play, testflight, fastlane

There is a [nice way](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_testflight/#add-a-new-tester) that let's us use the Fastlane CLI to add testers to TestFlight:

`fastlane pilot add email@invite.com`

How to do the same for Google Play Store test users?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible right now. If it does decome possible it will probably be part of [the Publishing API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/).